# Debug assertion failure

Tags: c++, debugging

I keep getting this debug assertion failure from my destructor when I try to free an array. The answer seems really simple but I can't quite figure it out. Any help would be appreciated. I'm a beginner (as you might have guessed) so a simple explanation would be lovely :)

```
// Class definitions
class Book {
public:
    string title;
    string author;
    int pubYear;
};

class Library {
private:
    Book *myBooks;
    static int getBookIndex;
    static int maxAmountOfBooks;
    static int currentAmountOfBooks;
public:
    void addBook(Book myBook);
    Book getBook(void);
    void showBooks(Library myLib);
    Library();
    ~Library();
};

// Constructor
Library::Library() {
    // Collecting user input
    cout << "Number of Books: ";
    cin >> maxAmountOfBooks;
    cout << endl;
    // Dynamically allocating memory
    this->myBooks = new Book[maxAmountOfBooks];
    cout << "Dynamically allocated library..." << endl;
}

// Destructor
Library::~Library() {
    // Freeing the dynamically allocated memory
    delete this->myBooks;
    cout << "Freed dynamically allocated library..." << endl;
}

 // Main
void main() {
    // Creating a Book object
    Book HarryPotter;
    // Filling Book object fields
    HarryPotter.title = "Harry Potter";
    HarryPotter.author = "JK Rowling";
    HarryPotter.pubYear = 1997;
    // Printing out the Book object fields
    cout << "Title: " << HarryPotter.title << endl;
    cout << "Author: " << HarryPotter.author << endl;
    cout << "Publication Year: " << HarryPotter.pubYear << endl << endl;

    // Creating a Library object
    Library myLib;
    // Callling Library member functions
    myLib.addBook(HarryPotter);
    Book retBook = myLib.getBook();
    // Printing out the Book object fields
    cout << "Title: " << retBook.title << endl;
    cout << "Author: " << retBook.author << endl;
    cout << "Publication Year: " << retBook.pubYear << endl << endl;
}
```

Comment: You're freeing an array: `delete this->myBooks` ==> `delete[] this->myBooks`.

Comment: Please post a [mcve]: yours is not *complete,* since the code of `addBook` and `getBook` is missing. And it's not *minimal,* since `showBooks` is never called.

Comment: Use std::vector. If you new[] you must delete[].

Comment: AAAAAAAAH Why do I still see this code on a daily basis. **Use `std::vector`.**

Comment: But otherwise, what @manni66 said: a C++ dynamic array is spelled `std::vector`. Don't manage memory manually, especially not when you're a beginner.

Comment: But, since you are passing in books to `addBook` by value, there may be other errors (like if you do `this->myBooks[this->currentAmountOfBooks] = &book` -- also, currentAmountOfBooks shouldn't be static, probably).

Answer (score 5):

Everything you `new[]` you must `delete[]`, `delete` does not suffice.

But the way more important piece of advice:

Start using containers that are in the standard library instead of using dynamic memory allocation manually and praying it works. They're in the standard library for a reason, use them. `std::vector` in this case.

At the end of the day you will be a happier person since you won't have to spend hours on debugging self-rolled containers.

Comment: Yes, good advice, but it is also valuable in itself for a new programmer to struggle with such problems. After all, you can't guarantee that a programmer will never have to work with an old code base that is littered with old-style idioms.